# How to switch qml renderer with pyside

Tags: python, qt, qml, pyside, pyside6

I use pyside6 for creating qml user interface. But this interface is working correctly only on windows 10. Running problems are connected with using qml render interface. So I need to switch render interface to [Qt Quick 2D renderer](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtQuick/QSGRendererInterface.html). But in official documentation i can't find how to do it with pyside

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is your specific question?

Comment: @eyllanesc I want to set QtQuick2D as QML renderer from PySide

Comment: use `os.environ["QT_QUICK_BACKEND"] = "software"` before `QXApplication` creation